# jQuery replace multiple words in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code to replace one word inside a div:

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
     An article about John and Steve
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#test').html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/John/g, 'Peter');
});
```

So John is replaced with Peter, but how can I replace also Steve with Beavis? I tried:

```
$('#test').html(function(i, v) {
        return v.replace(/John/g, 'Peter');
        return v.replace(/Steve/g, 'Beavis');
    });
```

How can I do that right?

Comment: return is the last instruction a function will execute. You can't return twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use chaining of `.replace()`:

```
$('#test').html(function(i, v) {
     return v.replace(/John/g, 'Peter').replace(/Steve/g, 'Beavis');
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :) I'll accept asap. Can you suggest me a good website where I can learn all this syntax besides w3schools and jquery.com?

Comment: @user3047382: you will find plenty of places if you google correctly :)

Comment: @user3047382: w3schools is the best place to begin with.